# defaultmessagelistenercontainer in spring

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I am trying to implement spring jms using following configuration:

```
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
     <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="2"/>
         <property name="destination" ref="responseQueue"/>
         <property name="messageListener" ref="adminListener" />

</bean>
```

and my message listener is implementing SessionAwareMessageListener

and in my onmessage(msg, session)

i am checking the acknowledgement, it is printing acknowlegemnt=1[AUTO] even though i am setting client acknowledgement in spring configuration.

destination bean code:

```
Connection con=connectionFactory().createConnection();

Session session_Temp=con.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
logger.info("session listener in listenerQueue method="+session_Temp.getMessageListener().toString());
```

this also returning acknowledgement=1 , if i change it to Session.Dups_ok, i can see its printing 3.

i dont understand why cant i set up message listener with client acknowledgment.

Any help can be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is your transaction configuration for the listener?

Comment: i am not using any transaction for listener. The following transaction is used by other part of my applicationpublic PlatformTransactionManager mfdTransactionManager()
 {
  DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
  transactionManager.setDataSource(mfDataSource());
  return transactionManager;
 }

Comment: do i have to add transaction manager to listner, cant i simply use transaction less asynchronous message listener??Thanks